# Stop board randomization after each command input

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

My program generates a new game board after every command I input. I only want the "P" to update the move while the board and obstacles stay the same until the game is terminated. Thanks for the help in advance, here is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

public class Adventure {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Create 2D array for game board.
    char grid[][]= new char[10][10];
    Scanner move = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Here is the current game board:");
    System.out.println("-------------------------------");

    do{
        for(int i=0; i<grid.length; i++) {          
            for(int j=0; j<grid.length; j++) {
                double Random = Math.random();
                if(Random <=.05) {
                    grid[i][j]='*';
                }
                else if(Random > .06 && Random <= .15) {
                    grid[i][j]='X';
                }           
                else {
                    grid[i][j]='.';
                }               
                grid[0][0]='P';
                grid[9][9]='T';
                System.out.print(grid[i][j]);
            }
            System.out.println("");
        }               
        System.out.print("Enter your move (U/D/L/R)>");     
        String movePlayer = move.next();

        int x=0, y=0;

        if(movePlayer.equals("R")) {
            grid[y][x]='.';
            x++;
        }
        else if(movePlayer.equals("L")) {
            grid[y][x]='.';
            x--;
        }
        else if(movePlayer.equals("U")) {
            grid[y][x]='.';
            y++;
        }
        else if(movePlayer.equals("D")) {
            grid[y][x]='.';
            y--;
        }
        else if(grid[y][x]=='*') {
            System.out.println("You fell in a pit. Game Over.");
        }
        else if(grid[y][x]=='X') {
            System.out.println("That spot is blocked. Please enter another move.");
        }
        else if(grid[y][x]=='T')
            System.out.println("Congratulations! You've found the treasure!");
        else {

            System.out.print(grid[y][x]);
        }
    }while('P' != 'T');
}
```

}

Comment: Please, for the love of all that is cool, break that into smaller functions. You will have such an easier time reading your code and figuring out bugs.

Comment: Also, `'P' != 'T'` will always be true.

Comment: You might want to look at your loop condition. I'm afraid 'P' can never be 'T'. I didn't write the alphabet, I just enforce it.

Comment: How would I make a statement to to terminate the game when P lands on T?

Comment: you want the value at position x,y to be 'T'.... you already did this just a few lines above

Answer (score 0):

move the code that generates the board outside the `do ... while()` loop:

```
// generate the board once at the beginning of the program.
do
{
  // update moves repeatedly until game is over
} while (<game over perdicate>)
```

Comment: When I put the code that generates the board outside the do while loop  and I enter a command, the board does not print.